# How to merge rows on specific condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of payments like this

```
Contract_Code  Payment_Year   Payment
470             2010           100
470             2015           50
470             2017           100
471             2011           60
471             2017           100
471             2018           100
```

and I need to view it but if year is after 2015 for example to combine rows with payments into one, kind of like this

```
Contract_Code  Payment_Year   Payment
470             2010           100
470             2015-2019      150
471             2011           60
471             2015-2019      200
```

Is it possible to do so and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code-

```
SELECT Contract_Code,
CASE 
    WHEN YEAR(Payment_Year) >= 2015 THEN '2015-2019' 
    ELSE CAST(YEAR(Payment_Year) AS VARCHAR) 
END Payment_Year,
SUM(Payment)
FROM payments
GROUP BY Contract_Code,
CASE 
    WHEN YEAR(Payment_Year) >= 2015 THEN '2015-2019' 
    ELSE CAST(YEAR(Payment_Year) AS VARCHAR) 
END
```

You can check the [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0c1daa48f7852297ccdefbc60f885e73)

Comment: Hi, it returns sum of all payments regardless of date. Not sure why. So Im getting this
```
Contract_Code  Payment_Year   Payment
470                      2015-2019          250
471                      2015-2019          260
```

Comment: Can you please check the DEMO? I have added the link to the answer.

Comment: Oh, I see that it works! Unfortunately my database is on SQL Server 2000, which im guessing is the reason it doesnt work for me. Upgrading is not possible, so I will have to look for another way. But thank you for answering, it totally works on newer versions!

Comment: This is so simple query and should work on your 2000 version as well.

Comment: I tried your code exactly, just changing the variable names to what I have and all im getting is sum of all payments on specific contracts
[link](https://i.imgur.com/vx8083c.png)

Comment: Can you give me the input data set for this output?

Comment: Query you written is OK. I guess there are no row with PayDate less then 2015!!

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry for the trouble [link](https://i.imgur.com/YMdFKRa.png)

Comment: As I observed your paydate column is holding date and time together, I made a small adjustment in the query. Just calculated YEAR from the DateTime field. Can you please check this works for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
---CREATE TABLE---
create table #payments(Contract_Code int,Payment_Year int,Payment int)
-----INSERT VALUES---
insert into #payments 
values('470','2010','100'),('470','2015','50'),('470','2017','100'),   ('471','2011','60'),('471','2017','100'),('471','2018','100')
 ----SELECT---
 select contract_code,convert(varchar,payment_year)payment_year,payment from #payments 
 where payment_year<2015
 union
 select contract_code
 ,case when max(payment_year)>=2015 then convert(varchar,min(payment_year))+'- 
'+convert(varchar,MAX(payment_year)) end payment_year
 ,sum(payment) from #payments where payment_year>=2015
 group by contract_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `case` expression for the `year` calculation.  You can do this using a `APPLY`:

```
SELECT p.Contract_Code, v.payment_year, SUM(p.Payment)
FROM payments p
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN p.Payment_Year >= 2015 THEN '2015-2019' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), p.Payment_Year) END)
     ) v(payment_year)
GROUP BY Contract_Code, v.payment_year;
```